# Handling function inputs in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Say I have a function

```
function u = somefxn(f,n)
```

where `f` is some function, say `f = pi^2*sin(pi*x)`, and n is the number of discretizations (let `n = 1024`) on the interval $[0,1]$. In my code I've written

```
h = 1/n %n = 1024
x = 0:h:1 %discretizations
```

But what if the user uses `y` or `z` in the function instead of `x`? How do I handle that uncertainty?

Please let me know if this isn't clear. I'm rather new to Matlab.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. The function `f` has (should have?) its own local variable, the name of which is independent of the calling scope.
2. It's much better to use `x = linspace(0,1,n+1)` than `x = 0:1/n:1` because the latter is susceptible to rounding error.

Comment: I'm confused about how functions are handled though. If I were to enter the same function but using f(y) instead of f(x), and my code includes x = linspace(0,1,n+1), then will it recognize that y should be treated as x?

Comment: Jed has explained the situation pretty clearly in his point #1, but perhaps using words and concepts that you do not know. When you define the function `f(something)`, inside the the function, `f`, the variable is known as `something` containing the argument you passed to `f`, but when you call `f`, you may pass the name of any variable you have already used/defined. So you may call `f(x)` or `f(y)` or `f(whatever)` as long as `x`, `y`, or `whatever` have been defined. Variable names in MATLAB are not shared between functions unless they are explicitly made global using the global keyword.

Answer (score 1):

I think I get your point, which [this answer](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/4922/3740) hasn't got.

Do you mean *literally* something like

```
x=1:0.1:10;
f=(pi^2)*sin(pi*x);
```

?

Then `f` is no longer a function. It is just a variable containing the **result of the function applied to the x** that you already have. In other words, your function has already been evaluated.

In this case, the answer to your question is that you don't need to do anything : `f` simply does not know about `x`, or other variable.

Depends on what's the exact code in question.